# Gostaria de fazer uma consulta relacional com sequelize do tipo right join

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, iot

Preciso realizar esse tipo de consulta com sequelize, para um retorno específico de dados.

```
"SELECT p.id, p.nome , p.numero_face, zp.zona_id from pessoa as p 
    right join zona_pessoa as zp on zp.pessoa_id = p.id where zona_id = 3";
```

Nesse exemplo de consulta a baixo eu trago os dados sem um relação com outra tabela "zona_pessoa", mas já tentei diversas formas e não conseguir tratar essa query.

```
async getPessoasSemFaces(req, res) {
    try {
      const pessoas = await Pessoa.findAll({
        where: { numero_face: { [Op.is]: null } },
        attributes: ['id', 'nome', 'numero_face'],
      });
      if (!pessoas) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Nenhuma pessoa sem face encontrada' });
      }
      return res.status(200).json(pessoas);
    } catch {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro interno' });
    }
  }
```

Comment: consegue colocar um modelo de dados de exemplo no SQL Fiddle e compartilhar aqui?
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Irei preparar um modelo, obrigado.